# Unable to check PHP to Database

Tags: php

I am trying to make a project on PHP to enter only one of the 3 options and get the other 2 details from the database. When I input the **$acecode**, I get the perfect result i.e the details of the employee. But, when I try to input **$acename** or **$acemail**, I get an error:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\WorkArea\HCLProject\submit.php on line 71

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\WorkArea\HCLProject\submit.php on line 80
No such record exists
```

-even though the record exists.

Please help.

My PHP Code

```
1    <?php 
2    
3    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project");
4    if(!$conn)
5       die("Connection failed" . mysqli_connect_error());
6    
7    $descr = $_POST['descr'];
8    $acecode = $_POST['acecode'];
9    $acename = $_POST['acename'];
10    $acemail = $_POST['acemail'];
11    $status = $_POST['status'];
12    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
13    
14    //check for acemail
15    if($acecode == NULL and $acename == NULL and $acemail != NULL)
16    {
17      $search = "SELECT * from empmaster where empmail=".$acemail;
18      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$search);
19      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
20      {
21          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
22          {
23              $acecode = $row['empcode'];
24              $acename = $row['empname'];
25          }
26      }
27      
28      else if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
29      {
30          echo "No such record exists";
31          $acemail = NULL;
32      }
33      else
34      {
35          echo 'Conflicting values found in Table "empmaster".';
36          $acemail = NULL;
37      }
38    }
39    
40    //check for acecode
41    else if($acename == NULL and $acemail == NULL and $acecode != NULL)
42    {
43      $search = "SELECT * from empmaster where empcode=".$acecode;
44      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$search);
45      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
46      {
47          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
48          {
49              $acemail = $row['empmail'];
50              $acename = $row['empname'];
51          }
52      }
53      
54      else if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
55      {
56          echo "No such record exists";
57          $acecode = NULL;
58      }
59      else
60      {
61          echo 'Conflicting values found in Table "empmaster".';
62          $acecode = NULL;
63      }
64    }
65    
66    //check for acename
67    else if($acecode == NULL and $acemail == NULL and $acename != NULL)
68    {
69      $search = "SELECT * from empmaster where empname like ".$acename;
70      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$search);
71      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
72      {
73          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
74          {
75              $acecode = $row['empcode'];
76              $acemail = $row['empmail'];
77          }
78      }
79      
80      else if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
81      {
82          echo "No such record exists";
83          $acename = NULL;
84      }
85      else
86      {
87          echo 'Conflicting values found in Table "empmaster".';
88          $acename = NULL;
89      }
90    }
91    
92    //last condition
93    else
94    {
95      $acecode=NULL;
96      $acename=NULL;
97      $acemail=NULL;
98      echo "Input only one value of Task Actionee";
99    }
100    
101    echo $acecode."<br>".$acename."<br>".$acemail;
102    ?>
```

Comment: Does $acemail stores a string ? 
If so, you should use ' to use it in a query, like this:

    "SELECT * from empmaster where empname like '$acename'";

Comment: Could you extract a [mcve]? There's a bunch of stuff that requires guessing otherwise, in particular all the inputs. The MCVE should demonstrate the error when you call it like `php mcve.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL query is wrong. You need to use quotes around the field:

```
$search = "SELECT * from empmaster where empmail='".$acemail."';
```

And again:

```
$search = "SELECT * from empmaster where empname like '%".$acename."%';
```

And you code is vunerable to SQL Injection attack. You should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You need to sanitize your input before using it in the SQL statement. You also need to put single quotes around the variable in your select.

```
// this needed single quotes around the variable
$search = "SELECT * from empmaster where empmail = '".$acemail."'";
```